# Extract data from dataframe if the column values are present in another data frame

Tags: pandas

B is a dataframe with some companies list

A is a  main data frame which has the column of "Companies list". Trying to extract data of data frame 'A' whose companies values are in data frame  'B'. I tried using  the below code :

```
df_a=df_a.loc[df_a['Company'].isin(df_b)]

But this is returning empty output. Below is the data
```

```
**df_b**

**Company**

A
B
C
D
E

**df_a**

**Company** **Date** **Orders**
A             Mon        1
B             Tue        2
R             Mon        1
T             Mon        1
U             Mon        1
T             Mon        1
Y             Mon        1
R             Mon        1
G             Mon        1
A             Mon        1
A             Mon        1
A             Mon        1


**Output** 

**Company** **Date** **Orders**
A             Mon        1
B             Tue        2
```

Answer (score 1):

I think problem is necessary select by column for `Series` in `df_b`:

```
df_a=df_a.loc[df_a['Company'].isin(df_b['Company'])]
```

Comment: Perfect. Worked. Thank you so much